# How is Pratt's gap sequence better than the gap sequences suggested by Shell, Hibbard, and etc.?

Tags: time-complexity, sorting

Pratt's paper suggests that the average time complexity for his gaps are $0.315 n(\log_2 n)^2$ (gaps generated from the ascending sequence of numbers in the form $2^p3^q$). Pratt's paper claims that $\Theta(n (\log_2 n)^2$ is better than all other shell gaps, suggesting the assertion, $n^{\frac{3}{2}}=o(n (\log_{2} n)^2)$. I doubt this assertion is correct since according the their graphs, $n (\log_{2} n)^2$ upper bounds $n^{\frac{3}{2}}$. The confusion might come from the  fact that the assertion, $n^{\frac{3}{2}}=o(n (\log_{10})^2)$ is indeed true but on logarithmic base 2 it is not.

Comment: Are you sure you are quoting correctly? $n^{3/2}$ certainly dominates $n \log^2 n$ asymptotically, trivially follows from the observation that $\log n \in o(\sqrt{n})$. The log base is irrelevant in the Landau notation, changing bases can be done "for free" (up to a multiplicative constant).

Comment: That's part of the reason why I'm confused since $n\log_2 n$ and $n\log_{10} n$ are supposedly the same in Landau notations but these two functions have different asymptotic relationships with other functions like $n^\frac{3}{2}$ or even $n^2$. [This](https://i.imgur.com/UKQpBDR.png) graph shows that $n^{\frac{3}{2}}$ (green) is between $n\log_2 n$ (blue) and $n\log_{10} n$ (magenta). What am I missing here?

Comment: Again, the keyword here is asymptotically. You can verify that $x \log_2^2 x - x \sqrt x = 0$ has a solution at $x = 2^{2^4}$. You have cut the plot too early to see the asymptotic behavior of the functions.

Comment: Wow you're right, I actually cut the [plot](https://i.imgur.com/VKO1XNR.png) way too short. $x\log_2^2 x−x\sqrt x=0$ actually has three solutions. Thanks for clearing this up.